# Access the history state of the previous page when a user clicks 'back'

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Is there a way using JS of accessing the history state of the previous page when a user clicks the 'back' button?

Comment: Do you load your content dynamically?

Comment: Yes. I've set up to use the HTML5 history API to navigate, but I have someting in the state that I need to use to ensure that an effect is correctly (but not unnecessarily) fired when the user clicks 'back'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately you're not allowed to read previous or next states.
All you can do is reading current state, using `history.state`.

But if it all happens on the same page without reloads, why don't you save data on you own stack. You can use array for this - just save the same data to array and new state.